# VS Code Shortcuts for {{}} and {%%}

Tags: pycharm, visual-studio-code

so ive been asking myself this for a while now (i'm pretty now to Django and vs code) but there must be some shortcut to writing all those {{ veriable }} and {% Django code %} in VSCode. I am typing {{ and }} and it is maddening to be honest.

I am pretty sure there are tonns of poeple how are new to python also interested in the answer, or maybe I'm the only one who did not figure this out ...

Im also using pyCharm for debugging occasionally. Does anyone know the shortcut for the problem above in pyCharm?

[sorry for saying Python instead of Django earlier]

Cheers

Comment: `{{` and `{%` aren't Python -- are you using Django templates or what? If so, look for a plugin in Pycharm. I know there's one for Twig which is extremely similar, but there's probably one specifically for Django. Once you enable that, you'll get the completions. Not sure abotu VSCode -- they don't have a 3rd party plugin system yet, do they?

Answer (score 0):

You could use [Djaneiro](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=thebarkman.vscode-djaneiro) for their snippets or [create your own snippet](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/customization/userdefinedsnippets#_creating-your-own-snippets) e.g. when you type `{{` then `tab` you will get `{{ [cursor] }}`

Comment: Awsome! I found a nice Extension for the Snippets! Now everythin works perfectly